# Removing words from a string

Tags: python, string

If I have a string such as `'the quick brown fox'`, how can I remove consecutive words, such as "quick brown" from the original string to get `'the fox'`? I tried `strip()`, which didn't work and I'm not particularly sure what else to do.

Comment: new_string=`'the quick brown fox'.replace(" quick brown ", " ")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `str.replace()`:

```
In [2]: strs='the quick brown fox'

In [3]: strs.replace('quick brown','')
Out[3]: 'the  fox'

In [4]: " ".join(strs.replace('quick brown','').split())
Out[4]: 'the fox'                          #single space between 'the' and 'fox'
```

`help()` on `str.replace()`:

```
S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> str

Return a copy of S with all occurrences of substring
old replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is
given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of `replace`.

Answer (score 1):

You *cannot* remove words from the *original* string. Strings are immutable; see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types):

> "Strings and tuples are immutable sequence types: such objects cannot be modified once created."

Using [`replace`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) returns a *copy* of the string.

Answer (score -1):

```
mystring.replace(" quick brown ", " ", 1)
```

Comment: replace " quick brown " with a space one time.

Comment: A semicolon?  Also, you may want to show assignment of the result as strings are immutable and the result will be lost unless it is assigned.